# mongodb aggregate nested nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

how i can find the document with $match on position 3 (only last item in array "ndr"). It is necessary that the aggreation search only in the last array-item of ndr.

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bd5c63a3d24b4a2e4cde03"),
    "name" : "great document",
    "country" : "us_us",
    "cdate" : ISODate("2017-03-06T12:56:03.405Z"),
    "nodes" : [ 
        {
            "node" : 3244343,
            "name" : "Best Node ever",
            "ndr" : [ 
                {
                    "position" : 7,
                    "cdate" : ISODate("2017-03-06T10:55:20.000Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "position" : 3,
                    "cdate" : ISODate("2017-03-06T10:55:20.000Z")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

I need this result after aggregation

```
{
    "name" : "great document",
    "country" : "us_us",
    "cdate" : ISODate("2017-03-06T12:56:03.405Z"),
    "nodes" : [ 
        {
            "node" : 3244343,
            "name" : "Best Node ever",
            "ndr" : [ 
                {
                    "position" : 3,
                    "cdate" : ISODate("2017-03-06T10:55:20.000Z")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Hi Josch, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you [edit] your question to show what you've tried so far, and what's going wrong with it?

Comment: What's your MongoDB server version?

Comment: I have version MongoDB Version 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation with Mongo 3.4 version.

The below query finds the last item `(-1)` using `$arrayElemAt` operator in the `ndr` array and stores the variable in `last` using `$let` operator for each `nodes` and compare the `last` variable `position` value using `$$` notation to `3` and wraps the `nbr` element within array `[]` if entry found and else returns empty array.

`$map` operator to reach `nbr` array inside the `nodes` array and project the updated `nbr` array while mapping the rest of `nodes` fields.

`$addFields` stage will overwrite the existing `nodes` with new `nodes` while keeping the all the other fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        nodes: {
            $map: {
                input: "$nodes",
                as: "value",
                in: {
                    node: "$$value.node",
                    name: "$$value.name",
                    ndr: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                last: {
                                    $arrayElemAt: ["$$value.ndr", -1]
                                }
                            },
                            in: {
                                $cond: [{
                                        $eq: ["$$last.position", 3]
                                    },
                                    ["$$last"],
                                    []
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Update:**

You can try `$redact` which  will keep the whole document if it finds the matching position from with the given filter.

`$map` to project the `true`, `false` values based on the filter for each of the nodes `nbr` position value and `$anyElementTrue` will inspect the previous boolean values for each doc and return a `true` or `false` value and  `$redact` will use the booelan value from above comparison; true value to keep and false value to remove the document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $redact: {
        $cond: [{
            $anyElementTrue: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$nodes",
                    as: "value",
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                last: {
                                    $arrayElemAt: ["$$value.ndr", -1]
                                }
                            },
                            in: {
                                $cond: [{
                                        $eq: ["$$last.position", 3]
                                    },
                                    true,
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, "$$KEEP", "$$PRUNE"]
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thx! how i can remove the whole document if not nodes.node.position matched with the given filter? At the moment the document would be in the pipeline.

Comment: Added a separate solution which will remove the document.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to unwind both nested arrays.

```
 db.<collection>.aggregate([
      { $unwind: '$nodes' },
      { $unwind: '$nodes.ndr'},
      { $group: {'_id':{'_id':'$_id', 'nodeID', '$nodes.node' },
                 'name':{'$last':'$name'},
                 'country':{'$last':'$country'},
                 'cdate':{'$last':'$cdate'},
                 'nodes':{'$last':'$nodes'}
                }
      },
      { $match : { nodes.ndr.position: 3 } }
  ]);
```

From here you can reassemble the aggregate results with a $group on the and do a projection. I'm not sure what your ultimate end result should be.

Comment: and how i can search only in the last array item?

Comment: Sorry I thought you were looking for a specific value "position:3" if you need to find the last you will need to use a $group and $last https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/

Comment: Hi, i need to find the document which hast position 3 in the last array item

Comment: Ok I modified the answer to include a $group and $last, this groups by _id and nodes.node this should let you search just the last nodes.ndr off each nested set.

Comment: uhhh this works nearly perfect, but what when i have more than one node? at the moment their push the document twice with the different node matches. how i can group by document ID and push the second node into  the node array?

Comment: After the $match you could do a second $group and perform a "nodes: {$push: "$nodes"}}" I think that will reconstruct the document if I am following what you are asking.

Comment: To clarify: if a document has two nodes that meet the position:3 criteria you want to return a single document with only those two nodes pushed into the nodes array? or do you want two results one for each occurrence?

Comment: HI, i want to return the whole document those one of the nodes meet the criteria position:x. if no nodes meet this critera than i want to get no document. i want only one document as result not for each node that meet the criteria. thx